# OpenCart: How to disable province display on the invoice?

Tags: php, html, templates, opencart, shopping-cart

Although we have provinces in the Netherlands we do not use them in an address (postcode is the most important thing with us). For this reason I disabled the province in the OpenCart checkout process. It still displays however on the invoice I print out, and since no province is filled in, the first province on the list is standard displayed, which is often the wrong one. For this reason I want to take away the province from the OpenCart invoice.

So I opened `admin/view/template/sale/order_invoice.tpl` and searched for the relevant part. Unfortunately, the address is referred to as `$order['payment_address']` and `$order['shipping_address']`. Somehow, that code prints out the address including breaklines (`<br />`).

My question is now: how do I disable just the province in the customer address displayed on the invoice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up also the controller class `admin/controller/sale/order.php` and check for the relevant parts where the `$order['payment_address']` and `$order['shipping_address']` are filled and comment out the appropriate lines (where the *province* is added to the string/array).

The same thing should also be done in the frontend - `catalog/controller/account/order.php`.

Should be something like this:

```
$find = array(
    '{firstname}',
    '{lastname}',
    '{company}',
    '{address_1}',
    '{address_2}',
    '{city}',
    '{postcode}',
    //'{zone}',
    //'{zone_code}',
    '{country}'
);

$replace = array(
    'firstname' => $order_info['payment_firstname'],
    'lastname'  => $order_info['payment_lastname'],
    'company'   => $order_info['payment_company'],
    'address_1' => $order_info['payment_address_1'],
    'address_2' => $order_info['payment_address_2'],
    'city'      => $order_info['payment_city'],
    'postcode'  => $order_info['payment_postcode'],
    //'zone'      => $order_info['payment_zone'],
    //'zone_code' => $order_info['payment_zone_code'],
    'country'   => $order_info['payment_country']  
);
```

You would probably also have to change the format line from

```
$format = '{firstname} {lastname}' . "\n" . '{company}' . "\n" . '{address_1}' . "\n" . '{address_2}' . "\n" . '{city} {postcode}' . "\n" . '{zone}' . "\n" . '{country}';
```

to (see the `/*` and `*/` comment):

```
$format = '{firstname} {lastname}' . "\n" . '{company}' . "\n" . '{address_1}' . "\n" . '{address_2}' . "\n" . '{city} {postcode}' /*. "\n" . '{zone}'*/ . "\n" . '{country}';
```

**To the comment:**

Now I am not sure, it is possible that the addresses format is stored within an order after it is created. In that case, change the appropriate lines in controllers to these:

```
/*if ($order_info['payment_address_format']) { // <-- same for $order_info['shipping_address_format']
    $format = $order_info['payment_address_format'];
} else {
    $format = '{firstname} {lastname}' . "\n" . '{company}' . "\n" . '{address_1}' . "\n" . '{address_2}' . "\n" . '{city} {postcode}' . "\n" . '{zone}' . "\n" . '{country}';
}*/

$format = '{firstname} {lastname}' . "\n" . '{company}' . "\n" . '{address_1}' . "\n" . '{address_2}' . "\n" . '{city} {postcode}' /*. "\n" . '{zone}'*/ . "\n" . '{country}';
```

Comment: [TOTAL EDIT] @shadyyx - Thanks for that detailed info. I commented out the lines as you suggested, but nothing seems to happen upon refreshing. I opened the page with another browser, just to check, but nothing there either.. Any other tip?

Comment: Since I tried to open the invoice on two different pc's with different browsers and seeing no difference, I presume that either the commenting makes no difference, OR the invoice is somehow cached inside the opencart installation. Is the last option realistic or is that nonsense?

Comment: I am not sure yet. I think your solution did solve the problem, but I think I'm simply unable to see it yet. I think that even despite your last edit OpenCart somehow still caches the invoices. I think this is so because I changed something else as well (in a language file) which also doesn't seem to update on the invoice. For this reason I need to make a new test order, which I will do later today. I will let you know if I have an answer!

Comment: If You did another changes and do not see them You are definitely editing a wrong files (or editing the right ones but looking somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution works:

edit in: `admin/controller/sale/order.php`

```
$replace = array(
                'firstname' => $order_info['shipping_firstname'],
                'lastname'  => $order_info['shipping_lastname'],
                'company'   => $order_info['shipping_company'],
                'address_1' => $order_info['shipping_address_1'],
                'address_2' => $order_info['shipping_address_2'],
                'city'      => $order_info['shipping_city'],
                'postcode'  => $order_info['shipping_postcode'],
                //'zone'      => $order_info['shipping_zone'],
                //'zone_code' => $order_info['shipping_zone_code'],
                'zone'      => '',
                'zone_code' => '',
                'country'   => $order_info['shipping_country']
```

First it didn't work, i thought it was a cache problem and clear all the cache, but it did not work. Then I searched on the request `order_invoice` and this was also used in `/system/storage/modification/admin/controller/sale`. After clear the modification cache it worked!